# How to Make a Nextjs 13 Page rendered Client side in the pages directory

Tags: next.js13

I have been trying to make a nextjs page client side but when trying to build nextjs pre-renders it thereby making functions that rely on `window`  object throw Errors.

Here are what I've done and still doesn't solve it.

- I have used the `"use client"` directive at the top of the page.
- Renamed the page extension to **.client.js** (Got this from ChatGPT)
- Imported `useEffect` and `useState` from react and even used a Suspense boundary
- Prevented any state from returning `null`

I expect the page to be client-side rendered.

I have been trying to deploy to production and this error keeps coming up because the page is pre-rendered. It worked on development.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it so the commands don't run until the window is actually loaded by wrapping each call in an if statement. This will avoid errors on the server side.

```
if (window) {
    // some window function (such as window.open())
}
```

(Sorry for brevity, not enough reputation to leave a comment)